# Disabling Zoom out on a GoogleMap object in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to disable the zoom (or set a unchangable zoom level) on my GoogleMap object. I did try disabling the Zoom Controls to false but that did not work for some reason. I am using the SupportMapFragment.

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);

....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was very simple,I was using the wrong method. Instead of that

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

I had to use this method:

```
mMap.getUiSettings(). setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);
```