# How to Stop the ZoomOut in android google map Api v2?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to stop google map ZoomOut when the zoom level reached to 9.0f.It seems map API2 does not have such method to control zoom level. Does anybody know any idea to solve this problem?..

Comment: map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false); try this

Comment: Thanks but this is use for to disable the zoom control and i want to disable the ZoomOut only.

Comment: changed this..mMap.getUiSettings(). setZoomGesturesEnabled(false);

Comment: hy check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369330/disabling-zoom-out-on-a-googlemap-object-android-google-maps-api

Comment: Thanks again...But it disable all zoom  and  i wants to disable only two finger zoomOut when zoom level reached at 10.0f. other zoom should be work like two finger zooIn, double tab zoom  etc

Comment: @khem Check whether you have any luck with this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3818042/5850835)

Comment: @khem, okay np. pls share yr code. i's try yr solution